# .htaccess Case-Sensitivity and File Extensions

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to do 2 things with my .htaccess file on https://example.com

1. I want all file paths to not be case sensitive. Currently all of my files and folder start with a capital letter.
2. I want all files to be able to be viewed and accessed without adding the file extension to the end.

My current .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 401 https://www.example.com
ErrorDocument 403 https://www.example.com
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.example.com
ErrorDocument 500 https://www.example.com

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com\.subdomains\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/example\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. I want all file paths to not be case sensitive. Currently all of my files and folder start with a capital letter.

Since the underlying filesystem path is mixed case you will need to use mod_speling (one `l`). (You will need access to the server config to ensure this module is enabled.)

Then you can use the following in `.htaccess`:

```
# Allow mixed case requests (mod_speling)
CheckSpelling on
CheckCaseOnly on
```

Note, however, that this triggers an external redirect to the correctly cased URL. So, if the user requests `/foo/bar/baz`, they will be externally redirected to `/Foo/Bar/Baz`.

However, if this generates a 500 Internal Server Error then mod_speling probably isn't installed.

> 2. I want all files to be able to be viewed and accessed without adding the file extension to the end.

I'm assuming you are referring to just the main `.html` (or `.php`) files that are part of your page requests and not literally *all* files, as in all static resources, eg. `image` / `image.jpg`, `mystyles` / `mystyles.css`, etc.

You would need to add something like the following immediately after the HTTP to HTTPS redirect and *before* the redirect that sends non-existent requests to an external server.

```
# Rewrite request to append file extension. eg. "/foo" to "/foo.html"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.\w{2,4}|/)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule (.+) $1.html [L]
```

The first *condition* avoids checks that the request does not already end with a file extension (or a slash - that indicates a directory). The side-effect of this is that you can't have dots in the final path-segment that "looks like" a file extension (an edge case that can usually be avoided). eg. `/example.foo` will not be rewritten to `/example.foo.html` (if that file should exist). But `/foo.example` could potentially be rewritten. This is an optimisation to avoid a lot of unnecessary filesystem checks.

The second condition checks that the corresponding `.html` exists before rewriting the request.

You need to make sure you are consistently linking to the URL without the file extension in order to avoid potential duplicate content issues (and exposing the file extension to your users).

If you are changing an existing URL structure then you can implement an external redirect to remove the `.html` file extension from URLs that are requested directly. This would be necessary in order to preserve SEO and any backlinks. However, this is not a replacement for changing the internal links in your HTML source to remove the `.html` extension.

If this is required then add the following before the above "rewrite":

```
# Redirect - remove the ".html" extension, eg. "/foo.html" to "/foo"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

NB: Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

---

**UPDATE#1:**

> It's using the LiteSpeed server.

Unfortunately, [mod_speling is not currently supported on LiteSpeed](https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php/litespeed_wiki:config:unsupported_apache_modules_by_lsws) - this is an Apache-only module.

And (unfortunately)... LiteSpeed does not "break" when it reads an error in the `.htaccess` file - it simply ignores it (silently). Which makes debugging these things that much harder.

You won't be able to make the URLs case-insensitive on LiteSpeed without a lot of work (read: it's not worth it). Just make sure you use correctly cased URLs throughout your site (or convert everything to lowercase).

---

**UPDATE#2:**

> I'm wanting that to work for all files including images and other static files.

Unless you have a very good reason for doing this I would recommend against that. Again, LiteSpeed does not support MultiViews/mod_negotiation - which would be "the easy" way to do this on Apache. (However, MultiViews can conflict with rewrites you might add later and cause you other problems unless you are experienced with this.)

To do this on LiteSpeed would be a rather tedious (and resource-intensive) process of manually checking every file extension to see whether it exists.

You can also have mime-type issues since the browser is unable to infer anything from the file extension. And users that downloaded anything will have to manually add the appropriate file extension for it to "work" locally.

This also opens you up to many "duplicate" issues unless you implement the redirect to strip the file extension.

Comment: I just added the first block of code that you gave me to the end of .htaccess and it doesn't work. Any ideas why? I tried going to https://example.com/examplefile.txt but it didn't redirect me to the actual file which is https://example.com/ExampleFile.txt

Comment: Did it not do anything - no error? Please confirm the webserver version you are on... Apache / LiteSpeed?

Comment: It just forwards through to `https://www.example.com/examplefile.txt` from the code I added last night in the other thread, even after clearing my browser cache and trying it on different devices. It's using the LiteSpeed server.

Comment: That presumably resulted in a 404? "And it's LiteSpeed." - Unfortunately, [mod_speling is not currently supported on LiteSpeed](https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php/litespeed_wiki:config:unsupported_apache_modules_by_lsws) - this is an Apache-only module. And (unfortunately)... LiteSpeed does not "break" when it reads an error in the `.htaccess` file - it simply ignores it (silently). You won't be able to do this on LiteSpeed without a lot of work.

Comment: Okay, never mind about that then. I'll remove it. The next thing is the file extensions. I'm wanting that to work for all files including images and other static files. The code you gave me looks like it'll only work for HTML files, though I haven't tried it yet. What would the code be for it to work for all/most types of files?

Comment: "I'm wanting that to work for all files including images and other static files." - Unless you have a very good reason for doing this I would recommend against that. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Understood. Could I add the code you gave more than once and change the extension specified in the code? I imagine that would work.

Comment: @RyderCragie Yes, that is what you would need to do, but this is going to run on every single request and filesystem checks are relatively expensive. So, you could end up with 100s of filesystem checks for every page request. You will also need to modify the rule that strips the file extension (this bit is fairly straightforward).

Comment: I'm guessing that's why it's not working? Can't show you my current file because it's too long, so here's a link: https://rydercragie.com/Temporary/htaccess2.txt

Comment: Sorry, there's a typo... it should be `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}`, not `%{DOCUMENT}`! I've updated my answer.

Comment: Update: I've fixed it! I added this:

```Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.html [L,QSA]```

Comment: I set this up for html and txt, and I have a file called ExampleFIle.html and ExampleFile.txt. It defaults the the html file if you don't add the extension. How do I change which one it defaults to? Does it depend on which order they're in in .htaccess?

Comment: @RyderCragie You should use the code that I provided in my answer (after the correction). That code is very inefficient and vulnerable to erroneous responses (500 errors, depending on the request). Yes, it depends on the order of the directives. First match wins.

Comment: I updated it to your code instead now that you corrected the typo. Thank you!

Comment: I have a directory named /Assets and I'm about to rename it to /assets but I don't want to break any links. How can I have /Assets redirect to /assets and keep all sub-paths present too?

Comment: @RyderCragie That is a straight forward directory redirect. (Needs to be implemented before your existing rules.) The fact that “Assets” and “assets” differ only by case is irrelevant, they are two different directories.

Comment: Bear in mind I've also got subdirectories which also begin with capital letters. /Assets/Homepage/Images (all need to redirect to completely being lowercase).