# Auto correct file extensions with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

If someone goes to `example.com/video.mov` and that's the wrong extension, what code can I add to .htaccess to have it auto-correct it to the correct file which would be `example.com/video.mp4`?

Comment: You could use a combination of a `RewriteCond` that checks if the file `/video.mp4` actually exists in the server side file system and then append a `RewriteRule` rewriting the request accordingly. You will find thousands of working examples for such thing here on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principle is very similar to "extensionless files" as outlined in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69723085/369434) to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69722063/htaccess-case-sensitivity-and-file-extensions), except that you need to check whether the requested file exists first. You may also need to force the appropriate mime-type for the new resource.

For example, if a request for `<anything>.mov` does not exist then internally rewrite the request to `<anything>.mp4` instead if that file exists, otherwise defaults to a 404.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite request from .mov to .mp4 on failure
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.mp4 -f
RewriteRule (.+)\.mov$ $1.mp4 [T=video/mp4,L]
```

The above does the following in order:

1. `(.+)\.mov$` - The `RewriteRule` *pattern* checks that the request ends in `.mov`
2. The first *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) checks that the request does not map to a file.
3. The second *condition* checks that the corresponding `.mp4` file does exist.
4. If the above checks are all satisfied the request is rewritten to the corresponding `.mp4` file.
   The `T` flag sets the appropriate `Content-Type` header on the response.